# How to make Google Play Store App like search action menu and search dialog design

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, material-design, search-dialog

As  per  new  material  design  update , the Google pay store  app action search opens a search  dialog thing once  tab on search action button. This search interface  is different  than a default action view  provided  by  android in action bar(which opens in action-bar only.)

So my question is  how to implement a new search action dialog like google play store app. Is  there any android official component or I have to create a custom dialog view for this? If  the  second one , then please show how to achieve  this  type of search view?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The following link might be helpful. It is a custom implementation of the search. Please have a look.

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

Answer (score -1):

its android default **searchview** with `android:iconifiedByDefault="true"` settings. the initial response that is shown to you after you click is based on your search history, i am guessing it will be saved, and later as you start typing in the edit text do the api call.

Comment: hi war_Hero. My first task is to open a search dialog like  the app shown above. but my search action opens a search edit box in action bar only now an overlay search dialog-box type. I have posted a screenshot above  f or this.

Comment: you need to add a  list view below the searchview and populate the listview based on the  response populate it

Comment: can you please show a example or  tutorial for  this? I am new to android. I am using the the search action menua s  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"></item>

Comment: Actually I  dont know where  to add ListView? Because I am not using any searchview exept the line in menu item.